# Heroku Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '-/firebase-config'

Tags: javascript, firebase, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a React project to Heroku, but when pushing files to the Heroku master branch, the build fails because of " Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '-/firebase-config' in '/tmp/build_0de13186/src' ".

How can I re-add/restore this missing module? Is it missing locally or remotely?

My react project consists of a server and a client which are both located in the same root folder. Both server and client have their own package.json with firebase installed.

```
     remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > fullstackapp@0.1.0 build
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '-/firebase-config' in '/tmp/build_0de13186/src'
remote:        
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: b577f7b18ab92dd19ec0a6e615586f97af15d9f6
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version b577f7b18ab92dd19ec0a6e615586f97af15d9f6
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to fullstackapp-portfolio.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fullstackapp-portfolio.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fullstackapp-portfolio.git'
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure and the code of file where youa re trying to import Firebase config?

Answer (score 0):

Frontend folder with the client files are located in the root map together with server.js

Firebase-config.js I located inside of the frontend folder root directory. The import of firebase-config.js that was failing happened inside of Frontend folder --> App.

[image]

[image: fjs]